# How can I create a list from raw_input ?

Tags: python, raw-input

```
while true:
    n = raw_input("put your family member's age. if you are done, put 'done'") # if I put int on n, I cannot put done.
    if int(n) == int():
        continue
    if n == str():
        print "ERROR"
        continue
    if n == "done":
        break
print #I couldn't make it
```

I want to make this program to count the number of family members and the sum of the family member's age

Q1. should I put int on n? but if I put int on n, It makes error when I put done. I want to put only numbers and 'done' in n

Q2. How can I count n? should I have to make a list?

Python is attractive thing. but when I meet problem, it makes me crazy.

Comment: Do you want to keep adding the `raw_input` to a list or make a list of size `n`?

Comment: @letsc yes I want to make a list with raw_input.

Comment: @CwsdfYasd, do you want to add each value entered to a list?

Comment: @letsc for example, I have a dad and mom and sister, and their age is 55, 50,18.and I'm 25.  I want to count the number and get sum of our family's age. first one could be 4 and the other could be 148.

Comment: @ForceBru any method is fine, but If possible, I want to use a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this, you append to a list, then print the list and the sum once the user types `done`. `isdigit()` avoids the need for a `try-except`, however keep in mind it only works for positive values, without decimal places. For ages, it should be quite appropriate:

```
age_list = []
while True:
    n = raw_input("put your family member's age. if you are done, put 'done'")
    if n.isdigit():
        age_list.append(int(n))
    elif n == "done":
        break
    else:
        print "ERROR"

print age_list
print sum(age_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the age in a `list` is the way to go. You can use  a `try except` block to know when the user is done.

```
ages = []
while True:
try:
    n = int(raw_input("put your family member's age. if you are done, put 'done'")) 
    ages.append(n)
except ValueError:
    break
```

Then you can do `len(ages)` to get the number of entries and `sum(ages)` to get the sum fo the ages

Comment: You want `except` instead of `expect`

Answer (score 0):

To put the items in a list, you create the list and use the append() method.

```
alist = []
while True:
    try:
        n = int(raw_input("put your family member's age. if you are done, put 'done'")) 
        alist.append(n)
    except ValueError:
        break
print sum(alist) # gives you the sum of the ages
```

However, if all you need is to count the total age, you do not need a list:

```
tot = 0
while True:
    try:
        n = int(raw_input("put your family member's age. if you are done, put 'done'")) 
        tot += n
    except ValueError:
        break
print tot # gives you the sum of the ages
```